# Ubuntu 20.04 not loading login components

Tags: boot, 20.04, login-screen

Today when I tried to start Ubuntu in a dual boot system with Windows 10, it takes me to a purple screen but the login components are not showing up. I can still see and move the mouse around.

I did not do major changes last night when it was working. Someone knows why is this and if it can be repaired?

Photo of the screen:

[image]

UPDATE: I'm able to get into the system on recovery mode, but I'm unable to connect to internet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've not disconected the 2nd screen and the login page was showing there.